# combine two aggregate values in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search and doing stats aggregation grouping by mac ID as shown below:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_state": {
                            "terms": {
                              "field": "Clients.MAC"
                             },
                             "aggs": {
                                        "stats_RxBytes": {
                                            "stats": {
                                               "field": "Clients.RxBytes"
                                              }
                                            },
                                        "stats_TxBytes":{
                                            "stats":{
                                              "field": "Clients.TxBytes"
                                              }
                                            }
      }
   }
}
```

Now I need to combine the two values from the aggs as below but not sure how to achieve it:

```
stats_TxBytes.sum + stats_RXBytes.sum
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sum aggregation`.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sum_bytes": {
      "sum": {
        "script": "doc['Clients.RxBytes'].value + doc['Clients.TxBytes'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You have to enable dynamic scripting: `script.disable_dynamic: false`

But be careful with this. See [this link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_enabling_dynamic_scripting)

Comment: Unfortunately this will sum up all the values together and he'll loose the stats.

Comment: When you use it in a sub aggregation you can stat the values on its scope.